# How can an object function as if it returns itself and another object?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and not sure how to word this question. Please let me know if there are key terms or concepts that I should be using. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.p = document.createElement("p");
    this.p.setAttribute("class", "awesome-p");

    this.span = document.createElement("span");
    this.p.appendChild(this.span);

    // do many things...

    this.go = function (class) {
        this.p.setAttribute("class", class);
        this.p.innerHTML = '';
        // do many other things...
    }

    return this;
}

myObj = new MyObject();
document.body.appendChild(myObj);
myObj.go(200);
```

Now, obviously if I `return this.p` then `appendChild(myObj)` works, and if I `return this` then `myObj.go()` works. But not both at the same time. Is there a way to do this, or am I going about this the wrong way?

I realize that I could `return this` then use `appendChild(myObj.p)`. But I think that forces me (or someone else) to know what will be returned specifically instead of expecting a generic HTML object that may be appended to the DOM.

Also, **ideally** I would prefer to use `myObj.go = 200` to perform the task rather than `myObj.go(200)` if it's within the scope of this question.

Note that setting the width is simply an example and that 'go()' will perform more functions than merely setting one attribute.

Comment: Just do `document.body.appendChild(myObj.p);`

Comment: You could set `MyObject`'s prototype to be that of an `HTMLElement`, then you can do appendChild.  But I heartily second Matt Burland's suggestion.  It just strikes me as weird design to inherit from an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).  It's better IMO to have an object that stores the Element.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of errors in your code, so to answer you first question: there are better ways to achieve your end goal. To setup an object, we use Prototypical Inheretance and you should attach methods of the object to the prototype like so:

```
var MyObject = function() {
    this.color = "blue";
    this.p = document.createElement('p');
    this.p.setAttribute("color", this.color);
    // do many things...
}

MyObject.prototype.go = function (color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

Please note that the use of the `color` attribute is deprecated and you should be using the `style` attribute instead. New code would look like:

```
var MyObject = function() {
    this.color = "blue";
    this.p = document.createElement('p');
    this.p.style.color = this.color;
    // do many things...
}

MyObject.prototype.go = function (color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

Because you wish to perform an action on the object (update the color attribute of the internal p element) you cannot achieve this through merely setting a property. You have to use a method, which unfortunately forces the `obj.go('red')` interface. The code as we have it above only sets the internal `color` property of `MyObject` to the passed `color` argument. We need another method that updates the p element:

```
var MyObject = function() {
    this.color = "blue";
    this.p = document.createElement('p');
    this.p.style.color = this.color;
    // do many things...
}

MyObject.prototype.go = function (color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.updateColor();
}

MyObject.prototype.updateColor = function () {
    this.p.style.color = this.color;
}
```

You can, however, achieve the interface you desire simply as:

```
var MyObject = function() {
    this.color = "blue";
    this.p = document.createElement('p');
}
var obj = new MyObject();
obj.p.style.color = 'red';
```

Read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for more on prototypical inheritance. It could help you greatly in your understanding of how objects work.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question.

Comment: My point was that you use `document.body.appendChild(myObj.p)`, when the question specifically states that the OP is trying to avoid that (hoping to just use `myObj`).  Your answer has good information, but it doesn't actually answer what the OP is asking.

Comment: His question is "Is there a way to do this, or am I going about this the wrong way"... He's looking for guidance and since there are so many errors in his code, I thought this would be the most appropriate way to guide him.

Comment: There are many other tasks performed in `go()`. Not just setting the color (which was an example). I've updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @Isius My answer still applies. You need to look into Prototypical Inheritance as you're not properly setting up your object. Using the prototype chain is the only way to get properties and methods properly attached to your newly instantiated object.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do something like this, though this works in modern browsers only.

```
function PElement (text) {
    this.p = document.createElement('p');
    this.p.innerHTML = text;
    this.p.color = 'blue';
    this.p.style.color = this.p.color;
    return this.p;
};

Object.defineProperty(PElement().constructor.prototype, 'go', {
    get: function () {
        return this.color;
    },
    set: function (x) {
        this.color = x;
        this.style.color = x;
        // You can execute more tasks here,
        // but the color (x) is the only argument,
        // and the context will be the P element
    }
});
```

[`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/constructor) and [`prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/prototype) at MDN.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tBfW/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You could return an object like { object: this, element: this.p }.
The caller would access properties of the object:

```
myObj = new MyObject();
document.body.appendChild(myObj.element);
myObj.object.go("red");
```